# Unable to Render 2D Array from Other Class

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d

***Libgdx Game***

**For some reason, my SpriteBatch is not able to render both of the 2d int arrays I use to build my dungeon(in class Dungeon1).**

I have created a random dungeon building algorithm which inputs into my 2d integer arrays. I'm trying to create a seperate Dungeon class with its own textures that implements the dungeon-building algorithm from the first class, but for some reason the map will not render.

In my main Game class I set my screen:

```
public class NanoRealms extends Game {
    @Override
    public void create() {
        this.setScreen(new Dungeon1(this));
    }
}
```

Then I use this class to build the dungeon:

```
public class Dungeon {

public static final int tileSIZE = 64;

private Random rand = new Random();

static int mapSize = 128;
static int[][] bg = new int[mapSize][mapSize];
static int[][] fg = new int[mapSize][mapSize];

private int roomCount = rand.nextInt(20) + 10;
private int minSize = 10;
private int maxSize = 20;

private ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
private Room[] room = new Room[roomCount];

public Dungeon() {      
    makeRooms();
    squashRooms();
    makeCorridors();
    fillRoom();
    Autotile at = new Autotile(mapSize, bg, fg);
}
...Dungeon Building Algorithm Goes HERE...
}
```

However, when I try to render the inputs I put into my 2 2d-Arrays, **it just wont work.**

You can see this in my render method of this class:

```
public class Dungeon1 implements Screen {

public Texture tiles;
public TextureRegion floor, wall, wallLeft, wallRight, tlCorn, trCorn, blCorn, brCorn, c1, c2, c3, c4;

float wh = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
float ht = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

private SpriteBatch batch;
private OrthographicCamera camera;

private int[][] fg = Dungeon.fg;
private int[][] bg = Dungeon.bg;

public Dungeon1(NanoRealms game) {
    Dungeon d = new Dungeon();
    tiles = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Map/tiles.png"));
    floor = new TextureRegion(tiles, 2 * 64, 0, Dungeon.tileSIZE, Dungeon.tileSIZE);
    wall = new TextureRegion(tiles, 64, 64, Dungeon.tileSIZE, Dungeon.tileSIZE);
    wallLeft = new TextureRegion(tiles, 0, 2 * 64, Dungeon.tileSIZE, Dungeon.tileSIZE);
    wallRight = new TextureRegion(tiles, 2 * 64, 2 * 64, Dungeon.tileSIZE, Dungeon.tileSIZE);
    tlCorn = new TextureRegion(tiles, 0, 64, Dungeon.tileSIZE, Dungeon.tileSIZE);
    trCorn = new TextureRegion(tiles, 2 * 64, 64, Dungeon.tileSIZE, Dungeon.tileSIZE);
    blCorn = new TextureRegion(tiles, 0, 3 * 64, Dungeon.tileSIZE, Dungeon.tileSIZE);
    brCorn = new TextureRegion(tiles, 2 * 64, 3 * 64, Dungeon.tileSIZE, Dungeon.tileSIZE);
    c1 = new TextureRegion(tiles, 3 * 64, 64, Dungeon.tileSIZE, Dungeon.tileSIZE);
    c2 = new TextureRegion(tiles, 4 * 64, 64, Dungeon.tileSIZE, Dungeon.tileSIZE);
    c3 = new TextureRegion(tiles, 3 * 64, 2 * 64, Dungeon.tileSIZE, Dungeon.tileSIZE);
    c4 = new TextureRegion(tiles, 4 * 64, 2 * 64, Dungeon.tileSIZE, Dungeon.tileSIZE);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(30, 30 * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/Gdx.graphics.getWidth()));
    camera.position.set(3000, 3000, 0);
    camera.zoom = 300;
}

public void render(float delta) {
    cameraInput();


    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    ////
    batch.begin();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.enableBlending();
    for (int x = 0; x < bg.length; x++) {
        float w = x * 64;
        for (int y = 0; y < bg[x].length; y++) {
            float h = y * 64;
            if (bg[x][y] == 1) {
                batch.draw(floor, w, h);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int x2 = 0; x2 < fg.length; x2++) {
        float w2 = x2 * 64;
        for (int y2 = 0; y2 < fg[x2].length; y2++) {
            float h2 = y2 * 64;
            if (fg[x2][y2] == 2) {
                batch.draw(wall, w2, h2);
            } else if (fg[x2][y2] == 3) {
                batch.draw(wallLeft, w2, h2);
            } else if (fg[x2][y2] == 4) {
                batch.draw(wallRight, w2, h2);
            } else if (fg[x2][y2] == 5) {
                batch.draw(tlCorn, w2, h2);
            } else if (fg[x2][y2] == 6) {
                batch.draw(trCorn, w2, h2);
            } else if (fg[x2][y2] == 7) {
                batch.draw(blCorn, w2, h2);
            } else if (fg[x2][y2] == 8) {
                batch.draw(brCorn, w2, h2);
            } else if (fg[x2][y2] == 9) {
                batch.draw(c1, w2, h2);
            } else if (fg[x2][y2] == 10) {
                batch.draw(c2, w2, h2);
            } else if (fg[x2][y2] == 11) {
                batch.draw(c3, w2, h2);
            } else if (fg[x2][y2] == 12) {
                batch.draw(c4, w2, h2);
            }
        }
    }
    batch.end();
    ////
}


public void cameraInput() {
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.Q))
        camera.zoom += 0.5;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.E))
        camera.zoom -= 0.5;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A))
        camera.translate(-10, 0, 0);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D))
        camera.translate(10, 0, 0);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S))
        camera.translate(0, -10, 0);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W))
        camera.translate(0, 10, 0);
}
}
```

When I put the render method and Textures from Dungeon1 into Dungeon, everything works fine. However, I want to create different styled dungeons with different textures without having to rewrite my dungeon algorithm every time.

Comment: Define "just won't work"

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what actually went wrong, so I'm just guessing.

The problem that jumps out at me is that Dungeon1 extends Dungeon, but does not call the super constructor, so your methods `makeRooms()`, `squashRooms()`, etc are never called. You do create a Dungeon object and then do nothing with it, so it's thrown away.

So at the top of your Dungeon1 constructor, replace

```
Dungeon d = new Dungeon();
```

with

```
super();
```

As a side note, it seems odd that you have the static arrays `bg` and `fg` in Dungeon, and then your subclass hides them with arrays that have the same name, but then directs those non-static arrays to point at the static arrays from Dungeon. This is convoluted, and a bug waiting to happen. These do not look like something that should be static, so I think you can remove the `static` key word from both of them. And the subclass does not need to reference them at all. It's a subclass, so it can access them normally without "re-referencing" them.

Comment: The Dungeon1 class is not actually a subclass of Dungeon, is only implements the Screen Interface.

Comment: I didn't notice that. I think I see... Dungeon1 is just a renderer, like a skin for the map? Like I said this is just a guess. You didn't say what actually doesn't work.

Comment: Yes that fixed it, and all the errors you stated I tweaked. Now dungeon1 extends dungeon and I have added a constructor to dungeon (). Thank you so much!!